# Convert PNG image to a PDF without margin

Tags: bash, pdf, pdf-generation, png, imagemagick-convert

I've a lot of PNG image (width: 3488px - height: 2116px), and now I need to put it in a pdf file to print over 500 pages

The problem coming when I convert the images, the PDF file has some margin and I need to put the image without any margin, or it will be resized

So i try this unix command (I'm doing this operation with imagemagick):

```
convert 675.png 674.png -extent 3508x2480 -border 0x0 test.pdf
```

Can you tell me how to do this operation?

PS: I've over 500 images, when I try to put all images, the convert command reply "Killed" after some seconds and it not create the pdf file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The extent given to `convert` is greater than the size of the images, may be the margin comes from that setting (in the [usage examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#extent) I can see space is added if the image is smaller), try without that setting.

Just in case you can't get the margin removed with `convert`...

I use `pdfcrop` from [texlive](http://tug.org/texlive/) to remove margins from pdf files.

Called like

```
$ pdfcrop in.pdf out.pdf
```

it should remove the margins from every page of *in.pdf* and it should place the result in file *out.pdf*.

In ArchLinux the command `pdfcrop` is provided by package [texlive-core](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/texlive-core/). Unfortunately I don't know about other distributions.

Comment: for debian/ubuntu, `pdfcrop` is in `texlive-extra-utils` pakage